# Avoid Materialize in Explain Plan while running Postgres Query

Tags: postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

I am trying to know the explain plan and optimize my query. Here is the query that I am using. While I am joining with pd_ontology table, I am seeing that the cost is increasing heavily.

```
explain create table l1.test as
select 
null as empi, 
coalesce(nullif(a.pid_2_1,''),nullif(a.pid_3_1,''),nullif(a.pid_4_1,'')) as id,
coalesce(nullif(pid_3_5,''),'Patient ID') as idt,
upper(trim(pid_5_2)) as fn,
upper(trim(pid_5_3)) as mn,
upper(trim(pid_5_1)) as ln,
nullif(pid_7_1,'')::date as dob,
upper(trim(pid_8_1)) as gn,
nullif(pid_29_1,'')::date as dod,
upper(trim(pid_30_1)) as df,
upper(trim(pid_11_1)) as psa1,
upper(trim(pid_11_2)) as psa2,
upper(trim(pid_11_3)) as pci,
upper(trim(pid_11_4)) as pst,
upper(trim(pid_11_5)) as pz,
upper(trim(pid_11_6)) as pcy,
coalesce(nullif(a.pid_13_1,''),nullif(a.pid_13_2,''),nullif(a.pid_13_3,''),nullif(a.pid_14_1,''),nullif(a.pid_14_2,''),nullif(a.pid_14_3,'')) as tel1,
coalesce(nullif(a.pid_13_1,''),nullif(a.pid_13_2,''),nullif(a.pid_13_3,''),nullif(a.pid_14_1,''),nullif(a.pid_14_2,''),nullif(a.pid_14_3,'')) as cell1,
lower(trim(pid_13_4)) as eml1,
upper(trim(pid_10_1)) as race,
upper(trim(pid_10_2)) as racen,
upper(trim(pid_22_1)) as ethn,
upper(trim(pid_22_2)) as ethnm,
upper(trim(pid_24_1)) as mbi,
upper(trim(pid_16_1)) as ms,
upper(trim(pid_16_2)) as msn,
coalesce(nullif(a.pid_11_9,''),nullif(a.pid_12_1,'')) as pct,
upper(trim(pid_15_1)) as pl,
upper(trim(pid_17_1)) as rel,
upper(trim(pid_19_1)) as ssn,
trim(obx_3_1) as rc,
--trim(o.cdscs) as rn,
null as rn,
trim(obx_3_3) as rcs,
trim(obx_5_1) as rv,
obx_6_1 as uru,
obx_8_1 as oac,
obr_25_1 as rst, 
rtrim(trim(replace(replace(regexp_replace(replace(obx_7_1,'x10E3','*10^3'),'[a-zA-Z%]','','g'),'^','E'),'*','x')),'/') as onrr,
trim(split_part(rtrim(trim(replace(replace(regexp_replace(replace(obx_7_1,'x10E3','*10^3'),'[a-zA-Z%]','','g'),'^','E'),'*','x')),'/'),'-',1)) as rrl,
trim(split_part(rtrim(trim(replace(replace(regexp_replace(replace(obx_7_1,'x10E3','*10^3'),'[a-zA-Z%]','','g'),'^','E'),'*','x')),'/'),'-',2)) as rrh,
obx_10_1 as natc,
orc_2_1 as "pon",
left(nullif(obx_14_1,''),8)::date as rdt,
case when to_date(nullif(obx_14_1,''),'yyyyMMddHH24miss') not between '1800-01-01' and current_date then null else to_date(nullif(obx_14_1,''),'yyyyMMddHH24miss') end as efdt,
case when to_date(nullif(obx_14_1,''),'yyyyMMddHH24miss') not between '1800-01-01' and current_date then null else to_date(nullif(obx_14_1,''),'yyyyMMddHH24miss') end as eldt,
coalesce(obr_16_1,'') as opid,
nullif(obr_16_13,'null') as opidt,
trim(orc_12_1) as opnpi,
--trim(upper(n.name)) as opn,
null as opn,
trim(nullif(obr_4_1,'null')) as oc,
trim(nullif(obr_4_3,'null')) as ocs,
trim(nullif(obr_4_2,'null')) as on,
to_date(nullif(obr_7_1,''),'yyyyMMddHH24miss') as ofdt,
trim(orc_5_1) as os,
--left(e.nte_3_1,512) as cmd,
split_part(b.filename,'/',5) as sfn,
'Clinical' as st,
now() AS ingdt,
'4' as acoid ,
'Test' as acon,
'result' as cltp,
'Test' as sstp,
'202' as sid
from l1.vipn_pal_historical_all_oru_pid a
join l1.vipn_pal_historical_all_oru_obx b 
on a.control_id = b.control_id
and b.cross_join_tuple_count = '0'
left join l1.vipn_pal_historical_all_oru_obr c 
on a.control_id = c.control_id 
and b.order_observation_order = c.order_observation_order
and a.cross_join_tuple_count = '1'
left join l1.vipn_pal_historical_all_oru_orc d 
on a.control_id = d.control_id 
and d.order_observation_order = b.order_observation_order 
and a.cross_join_tuple_count = '1'
left join (select control_id ,order_observation_order ,observation_order,replace(string_agg(nte_3_1 ,' '),'\.br\',chr(13)||chr(10)) as nte_3_2
        from l1.vipn_pal_historical_all_oru_nte   
        group by control_id ,order_observation_order ,observation_order ) e
on a.control_id = e.control_id and e.observation_order = b.observation_order 
and e.order_observation_order = b.order_observation_order
--and e.cross_join_tuple_count = '1'
left join (select * from l2.pd_ontology where dtp = 'result') o 
on (b.obx_3_1 = o.cval or b.obx_3_1 = cvald)
left join l2.pd_npi n 
on d.orc_12_1 = n.npi;
```

Here is the explain Plan generated where you can see that the materialize is taking load.

```
Merge Left Join  (cost=106313.03..7599360149686.98 rows=329075452 width=1641)
  Merge Cond: ((a.control_id)::text = (c.control_id)::text)
  Join Filter: (((a.cross_join_tuple_count)::text = '1'::text) AND ((b.order_observation_order)::text = (c.order_observation_order)::text))
  ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=106311.69..7599175158271.60 rows=329075452 width=244)
        Merge Cond: ((a.control_id)::text = (d.control_id)::text)
        Join Filter: (((a.cross_join_tuple_count)::text = '1'::text) AND ((d.order_observation_order)::text = (b.order_observation_order)::text))
        ->  Merge Join  (cost=106310.57..7599144659758.97 rows=329075452 width=236)
              Merge Cond: ((a.control_id)::text = (b.control_id)::text)
              ->  Index Scan using vipn_pal_historical_all_oru_pid_control_id_idx on vipn_pal_historical_all_oru_pid a  (cost=0.56..800918.31 rows=9353452 width=96)
              ->  Materialize  (cost=106309.92..7599139604853.41 rows=282211264 width=161)
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=106309.92..7599138899325.25 rows=282211264 width=161)
                          Join Filter: (((b.obx_3_1)::text = (pd_ontology.cval)::text) OR ((b.obx_3_1)::text = (pd_ontology.cvald)::text))
                          ->  Index Scan using vipn_pal_historical_all_oru_obx_control_id_idx on vipn_pal_historical_all_oru_obx b  (cost=0.57..53285968.32 rows=282211264 width=161)
                                Filter: ((cross_join_tuple_count)::text = '0'::text)
                          ->  **Materialize  (cost=106309.35..1255207.79 rows=1538682 width=19)**
                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on pd_ontology  (cost=106309.35..1247514.38 rows=1538682 width=19)
                                      Recheck Cond: ((dtp)::text = 'result'::text)
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pd_ont_idx_dtp  (cost=0.00..105924.68 rows=1538682 width=0)
                                            Index Cond: ((dtp)::text = 'result'::text)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=1.12..14373643.76 rows=18706904 width=29)
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.12..14326876.50 rows=18706904 width=29)
                    ->  Index Scan using vipn_pal_historical_all_oru_orc_control_id_idx on vipn_pal_historical_all_oru_orc d  (cost=0.56..2587122.40 rows=18706904 width=29)
                    ->  Index Only Scan using idx_pd_npi_npi on pd_npi n  (cost=0.56..0.62 rows=1 width=11)
                          Index Cond: (npi = (d.orc_12_1)::text)
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.57..12676277.17 rows=80915472 width=60)
        ->  Index Scan using vipn_pal_historical_all_oru_obr_control_id_idx on vipn_pal_historical_all_oru_obr c  (cost=0.57..12473988.49 rows=80915472 width=60)
```

Is there a way to avoid Materialize in query and optimize it?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the index to solve this issue. The Materialize is re-scanning and to avoid that, I dropped the index. Now materialize will not do an index scan and hence, it does not need to re-scan. Saving cost!!